# Update value in object with a variable property name in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've got this method:

```
updateDate(row: TaskItem, column: keyof TaskItem, date: string) {
  row[column] = date;
}
```

Where TaskItem looks like this:

```
export interface TaskItem {
  id: number,
  myDate: string
}
```

And I want to be able to call it like this:

```
updateDate(rowItem, 'myDate', '2022-02-20');
```

However, TS doesn't like it:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

It works as soon as I change `row: TaskItem` to `row: any`, but I'd like to be more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is completely correct, because your `updateDate` function assumes that the new value (`date`) is *typeof* `string`. However, you are not specifying which field exactly you want to update, so you have small conflict here, because even if the new value is *typeof* `string`, there is still a possibility that the `column` will be `id` (`column: 'id' | 'myDate'`) which **is not** typeof `string` but a `number`.

Either you should make this function `updateDate` responsible **only** for updating the `myDate` field:

```
function updateDate(row: TaskItem, date: string) {
  row.myDate = date
}
```

or add a condition to make sure that you update only `myDate` field:

```
function updateDate(row: TaskItem, column: keyof TaskItem, date: string) {
  if (column === 'myDate') {
     row[column] = date
  }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADgEwIZQKYBEvYAUATnAO4BciAKhgM4DWAkjgLYA0iEcANiK2CoNsATzjAa9Zm06YcVOlGIwwAcwCUiAN4AoRPsQwJhbnwGIAvFcQByViPw4bm3QbeJSZANqn%20YALqWiHLYegYAvjqROqCQsAjI6AQAUiCKjkSeVLSMLNgcwQQKSioa2mH6ngB09hlBIVE6OtgAHihwxFCGYDjEwBgQ2JK5bOX6MGhUYPwARtjE7GG1RYiKymqNOtxgih7keaxBrgYTVACMi27L8rY2i9GoIRkk%20zK219h3tgBMAAzf3wAtP9AX9nABuIA)

Answer (score 2):

This can be nicely solved with generics to work safely with any object type, enforcing that the second parameter can only be a key of `obj` and that the third parameter is enforced to be the same type as `typeof obj[key]`.

```js
function updateProp<TObj, K extends keyof TObj>(obj: TObj, key: K, value: TObj[K]) {
    obj[key] = value;
}

interface TaskItem {
    id: number,
    myDate: string
}

declare const rowItem: TaskItem;

updateProp(rowItem, 'myDate', '2022-02-20');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADgEwIZQKYAUBOcKAPACoDyARgFYA0iA0otgB45hoDOiA1tgJ5xgiCjQB8ACjg0AXCKp1eAuQ3oA3DABsQ2OaOoBtBgF0AlIgDeAWABQie4mmG+-Y4gC8iDduwBuWwC+trYwYDj4wBgQ2CIYnDwAkjgAtpa2DogwaHJgIMmU2Pi06Q7J-AAiWLqInFD4oQDmgcE2aNgQmhj4MRAItYiEAO5J2Ml6cYkp-ja2qJg4BEQSQyPJ9ADkZZU46xsATAAMe3sAtEcnh+umvkA)